# Google SDK crashes in iOS 8 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios8, gmsmapview

I imported the latest `GoogleMaps` framework in my application. In `.m` file, I do import `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` and in `viewDidLoad:`, I create the map with line

```
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 428.0f) camera:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

No time before the `mapView` loads the map tiles, the application crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x11f0)`

But the same works after in release mode. No crash is observed in release mode and the `mapView` works fine. Only in debugging mode, the app crashes and leaves no hint.

This happens in iOS versions 8 and above 8. Debugging works fine without crash on iOS 7.

This is something fishy. Any approach that I could figure it out?

Comment: You probably using a old version of Google Maps iOS SDK. Now, you can easily integrate Google Maps iOS SDK using CocoaPods, you can see [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_3_install_the_api_using_cocoapods) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to @ztan's comment, adding CocoaPods solved the problem